# PS4 controllers not working

Tags: ps4, controllers, psn

I'm sorry in advance if this is not the right place, but I don't know where else to post this.

I have four PS4 controllers and I haven't used two of them for at least 6 months...last night I charged them, and nothing happened.

When I plug them (into my PS4 with a USB cable) I get this yellow blinking light and after a while, it stops. When I press the ps button to turn them on I get a blue blinking light that eventually turns off...and again nothing happens.

Things I have tried without any luck:

- Different USB cables (about 3 cables).
- Factory resetting my controllers (sticking a clip in the back of the
  controller for 10 seconds).
- Also restarted the controller by pressing the share button for 3
  seconds, then holding the ps button for 5 seconds.
- Torn one of the controllers apart, disconnected the battery for about
  4 hours, put everything back, same.
- Unplugged my PS4 from the power supply for 2 hours.

My PS4 won't detect those two controllers, they don't appear under the Bluetooth settings, this is really really weird.

I don't know what to do, does anyone knows something about this issue?